# How to reference a custom helper in controller method as I did in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I made a grid helper in `App_Code` called `ControlHelper` and it works just fine. I renders a form and a table with inputs and has buttons to submit all the information back to a method of my choosing.

[image]

I can tell that the controller code to handle the submits off this grid is going to be the same every time, so I added a method called `Submit()` onto my helper to reuse that code.

I can successfully call the helper method to render the grid from my view with

```
@ControlHelper.Grid(Html, Model, "About", "Home")
```

But when I try to call `ControlHelper.Submit()` from my controller code it says my helper is undefined.

> The name 'ControlHelper' does not exist in the current context

Here's the relevant part of the code of the helper:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc;
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
@using male.services.biz

@functions
{
  public static HelperResult Grid<TModel, T>(HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    EFCollection<T> collection,
    string action,
    string controller,
    FormMethod method = FormMethod.Post,
    string formName = null) where T : EFObject<T>
  {
    formName = formName ?? "frm" + typeof(T).Name + "s";
    return RenderGrid(html, typeof(T), collection, action, controller, method, formName);
  }

  public static void Submit<T>(EFCollection<T> collection, string save, string add, string delete) where T : EFObject<T>
  {
    if (add == null)
      collection.Remove(collection.Last());

    if (delete != null)
    {
      var itemToDelete = collection[int.Parse(delete)];
      collection.Remove(itemToDelete);
      itemToDelete.Delete();
    }
    if (add != null || delete != null || save != null)
      collection.Save();
  }
}
```

My controller code currently is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult About(EFCollection<Member> members, string save, string add, string delete)
{

  if (add == null)
    members.Remove(members.Last());

  if (delete != null)
  {
    var memberToDelete = members[int.Parse(delete)];
    members.Remove(memberToDelete);
    memberToDelete.Delete();
  }
  if (add != null || delete != null || save != null)
    members.Save();
  return View(members);
}
```

but see if I can get this to work it will reduce to just:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult About(EFCollection<Member> members, string save, string add, string delete)
{
  ControlHelper.Submit(members, save, add, delete);
  return View(members);
}
```

Comment: Why did you put your helper in a razor view ?
You can not call functions from your controller to a razor view.

Comment: @RalfD'hooge, My helper is not in a razor view it's in App_Code. I'm not trying to call controller from the view; I'm trying to call the helper from my controller. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, I don't do this like this any more. I use shared edit / display views for certain types and classes to achieve what I want.